# How Tortoise Hg authenticates users?

Tags: authentication, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

I am using **Tortoise Hg** for managing my *Mercurial* repositories (Clone,Push etc.). But I am not clear about how Tortoise Hg authenticates users. If I *Clone* or *Push* a protected repository, **Tortoise Hg** will ask for user credentials. If I enter the credentials, how is Tortoise hg authenticating the user (I mean the background process) ? How can I create a user in **Tortoise Hg** like in **Tortoise SVN**. Anybody knows the answer please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "create a user in TortoiseHG".

THG just asks you what server asked, nothing more. And it doesn't persist it anywhere unless you've done some additional steps.

> If I enter the credentials, how is Tortoise hg authenticating the user (I mean the background process) ?

THG doesn't authenticate your user, it just sends the credentials as is-to the server.

In your case it's just a basic authentication, and if you want to persist it - you can either hardcode it in `[auth]` section of your `hgrc` (either repository level one, or global) or use `mercurial_keyring` extension. The latter is preferred.

Comment: Also try to take a look at [this tutorial about SSH for Mercurial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial). Hope it will help you.

Comment: @zerkms@ufo: Thanks for your reply. Now I have a doubt. How users are created in Assembla? I want to make a functionality like that in my local system.

Comment: @Arjun: well, it depends on how you provide an access to the repositories. I would recommend you to have a look at [mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/mercurial-server.html) It's a terribly easy and flexible way to share repositories and control permissions